# How To Config Lettuce Redis cluster Async Connection Pool

Tags: spring, redis, lettuce

I'm configuring my lettuce rediscluster pool. When I configure it according to the official documentation, the connection pool cannot be initialized properly and I can't get the connection. The official docs state:

```
RedisClusterClient clusterClient = 
RedisClusterClient.create(RedisURI.create(host, port));

AsyncPool<StatefulRedisConnection<String, String>> pool =             AsyncConnectionPoolSupport.createBoundedObjectPool(        () -> clusterClient.connectAsync(StringCodec.UTF8),     BoundedPoolConfig.create());
// execute work
CompletableFuture<String> setResult = pool.acquire().thenCompose(connection -> {        
    RedisAsyncCommands<String, String> async = connection.async();    
    async.set("key", "value");
    return async.async.set("key2", "value2").whenComplete((s, throwable) -> pool.release(c));
});

// terminating
pool.closeAsync();

// after pool completion
client.shutdownAsync();
```

this config not work in my environment .then i add minIdle config :

```
final BoundedPoolConfig.Builder builder = BoundedPoolConfig.builder();
builder.minIdle(9);
```

It worked at the beginning, but when I loop through the connection pool and send commands from multiple times, the following exeception is thrown:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException:             AsyncPool is closed   at     java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:357) at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1895)
```

Here are all my code:

```
private String passwd = "xxxxx";
private String ip = "10.0.0.204";
;

@Bean
@Scope("singleton")
public ClientResources clientResources() {
    final DefaultClientResources defaultClientResources = DefaultClientResources.builder()
                                                                                .ioThreadPoolSize(4)
                                                                                .computationThreadPoolSize(4)
                                                                                .build();

    return defaultClientResources;
}

@Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
@Scope("singleton")
public RedisClusterClient clusterClient(ClientResources clientResources) {
    final String ip = "10.0.0.204";
    final String passwd = "dingXiang123";
    final RedisURI redisURI1 = RedisURI.Builder.redis(ip, 7001).withPassword(passwd).build();
    final RedisURI redisURI2 = RedisURI.Builder.redis(ip, 7002).withPassword(passwd).build();
    final RedisURI redisURI3 = RedisURI.Builder.redis(ip, 7003).withPassword(passwd).build();
    final RedisURI redisURI4 = RedisURI.Builder.redis(ip, 7004).withPassword(passwd).build();
    final RedisURI redisURI5 = RedisURI.Builder.redis(ip, 7005).withPassword(passwd).build();
    final RedisURI redisURI6 = RedisURI.Builder.redis(ip, 7006).withPassword(passwd).build();
    RedisClusterClient clusterClient = null;
    try {
        final List<RedisURI> redisURIS = Arrays.asList(redisURI1, redisURI2, redisURI3, redisURI4, redisURI5, redisURI6);
        clusterClient = RedisClusterClient.create(clientResources, redisURIS);
        ClusterTopologyRefreshOptions topologyRefreshOptions = ClusterTopologyRefreshOptions.builder()
                                                                                            .enableAdaptiveRefreshTrigger(ClusterTopologyRefreshOptions.RefreshTrigger.MOVED_REDIRECT, ClusterTopologyRefreshOptions.RefreshTrigger.PERSISTENT_RECONNECTS)
                                                                                            //连接池refresh超时时间
                                                                                            .adaptiveRefreshTriggersTimeout(Duration.ofMinutes(3))
                                                                                            .build();


        clusterClient.setOptions(ClusterClientOptions.builder()
                                                     .topologyRefreshOptions(topologyRefreshOptions)
                                                     .autoReconnect(true)
                                                     .pingBeforeActivateConnection(true)
                                                     .build());

        final RedisAdvancedClusterAsyncCommands<String, String> async = clusterClient.connect().async();
        final RedisFuture<String> set = async.set("aa", "aaaaa");
        set.get();
        log.info("客户端初始化成功");
        return clusterClient;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("lettce客户端初始化失败，{}", e);
        if (clusterClient != null) {
            clusterClient.shutdown();
        }
    }

    return null;
}

/**
 * 初始化异步的 Cluter 模式链接池
 *
 * @param clusterClient
 * @return
 */
@Bean()
@DependsOn("clusterClient")
@Scope("singleton")
public BoundedAsyncPool<StatefulRedisClusterConnection<String, String>> lettucePool(RedisClusterClient clusterClient) {
    final BoundedPoolConfig.Builder builder = BoundedPoolConfig.builder();
    builder.minIdle(9);
    final BoundedPoolConfig boundedPoolConfig = builder.build();
    final BoundedAsyncPool<StatefulRedisClusterConnection<String, String>> lettucePool = AsyncConnectionPoolSupport.createBoundedObjectPool(
            () -> clusterClient.connectAsync(StringCodec.UTF8)
            , boundedPoolConfig
    );


    log.info("连接池初始化成功");
    return lettucePool;
}

/**
 * 从连接池获取链接
 *
 * @param lettucePool
 */
@Bean
@DependsOn("lettucePool")
public CompletableFuture<StatefulRedisClusterConnection<String, String>> clusterAsync(BoundedAsyncPool<StatefulRedisClusterConnection<String, String>> lettucePool) {

    final CompletableFuture<StatefulRedisClusterConnection<String, String>> acquire = lettucePool.acquire();
    return acquire;
}
```

1. Have you encountered this problem again, how did you solve it?
2. The other point is that I don't really like redisTemplate to operate the letuce API, so I am looking for a configuration solution for the native Lettuce cluster pool.
3. Have you done the configuration of the original cluster pool or the use of Api before, or have seen the detailed Demo documentation, if you have, please recommend it to me (of course, I also read the official document, I may Need a Demo Application to study )