# Is Spring Redis/Lettuce client bottlenecked in NIO event loop?

Tags: spring, kotlin, redis, spring-data-redis, lettuce

I'm building a Spring application to capture data from ~100 websocket clients, then store the data in a queue-like way in a Redis server. The issue is that the server starts to freeze up over time, and eventually the websocket clients disconnect due to host timeouts.

I initially thought the issue was with using Spring Redis Repositories, but the issue persisted once I switched to Redis Templates.

I then thought that the issue was with (de)serialization of Redis objects, and for some time, it was the issue. Through profiling, I found that parsing doubles from strings is slow (when processing thousands per second), so I instead wrote a serialization function to convert double arrays into byte arrays for Redis. This greatly reduced CPU time.

```kotlin
fun DoubleArray.toBytes(): ByteArray {
    val buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(DOUBLE_SIZE_BYTES * size)
    forEachIndexed { i, d -> buffer.putDouble(DOUBLE_SIZE_BYTES * i, d) }
    return buffer.array()
}
```

```kotlin
open class SingleSampleRepository<T : SampleModel>(
    private val tClass: KClass<T>,
    template: RedisTemplate<String, ByteArray>
) {
    private val ops = template.opsForValue()
    private val keyName = "ValueOf${tClass.simpleName}"

    fun find(deviceId: Long): T? {
        val name = "$keyName:$deviceId"
        return SampleModelHelper.deserializeFromBytes(tClass, ops.get(name) ?: return null)
    }

    fun save(deviceId: Long, sample: T) {
        val name = "$keyName:$deviceId"
        ops.set(name, sample.serializeToBytes())
    }
}
```

```kotlin
open class MultiSampleRepository<T : SampleModel>(
    private val tClass: KClass<T>,
    private val template: RedisTemplate<String, ByteArray>,
    private val maxSamples: Int = MAX_SAMPLES
) {
    companion object {
        private const val SAMPLES_HZ = 50
        private const val TIME_DURATION_SECONDS = 120
        const val MAX_SAMPLES = TIME_DURATION_SECONDS * SAMPLES_HZ
    }

    private val ops = template.opsForZSet()
    private val keyName = "ZSetOf${tClass.simpleName}"
    private val scoreProperty = tClass.memberProperties.first { it.hasAnnotation<RedisScore>() }

    fun findAll(deviceId: Long): Set<T> {
        val name = "$keyName:$deviceId"
        return ops.range(name, 0, ops.size(name) ?: 0)?.map {
            SampleModelHelper.deserializeFromBytes(tClass, it)
        }?.toSet() ?: emptySet()
    }

    fun saveAll(deviceId: Long, samples: Set<T>) {
        val name = "$keyName:$deviceId"
        template.delete(name)
        ops.add(name, samples.map {
            ZSetOperations.TypedTuple.of(it.serializeToBytes(), scoreProperty.get(it) as Double)
        }.toMutableSet())
        while ((ops.size(name) ?: 0) > MAX_SAMPLES) ops.popMin(name)
    }

    fun save(deviceId: Long, sample: T) {
        val name = "$keyName:$deviceId"
        ops.add("$keyName:$deviceId", sample.serializeToBytes(), scoreProperty.get(sample) as Double)
        while ((ops.size(name) ?: 0) > MAX_SAMPLES) ops.popMin(name)
    }
}
```

I now suspect that the spring-data-redis Lettuce client is the issue. Specifically, Lettuce seems to only use one NIO event loop thread. I don't know if this is a good/bad thing, so please let me know if it's working correctly. Here are some screenshots from profiling:

[image]

[image]

I also tried using ClientResources and custom thread pools after seeing other posts about Lettuce, but none of these methods increased the NIO event loop thread count.

- [How to pass own executors to the redis lettuce library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61337360/how-to-pass-own-executors-to-the-redis-lettuce-library)
- [Since redis 6 use multi thread now, does lettuce better use connection pool now?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64999787/since-redis-6-use-multi-thread-now-does-lettuce-better-use-connection-pool-now)
- [How To Config Lettuce Redis cluster Async Connection Pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51571044/how-to-config-lettuce-redis-cluster-async-connection-pool)
- [Spring Data Redis - Lettuce Connection Pool Setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61159991/spring-data-redis-lettuce-connection-pool-setting)
- [Redis connection pool configured using spring-data-redis but not working correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63684915/redis-connection-pool-configured-using-spring-data-redis-but-not-working-correct)

I understand that Redis itself is mostly single-threaded, but from profiling, it looks like most CPU time is spent on encoding/decoding Redis commands, not actually sending them. Should Lettuce be using multiple threads for the NIO event loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to setting shareNativeConnection to false, I also had to set up the LettucePoolingClientConfiguration. This combination finally increased the thread count, and I saw greatly improved performance.

```kotlin
@Configuration
class RedisConfig {
    @Bean
    fun connectionFactory(): RedisConnectionFactory {
        val redisConfig = RedisStandaloneConfiguration()
        val clientConfig = LettucePoolingClientConfiguration.builder().build()
        val factory = LettuceConnectionFactory(redisConfig, clientConfig)
        factory.shareNativeConnection = false
        return factory
    }
}
```

Comment: It's also worth noting that pipelining ([Spring docs here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/reference/html/#pipeline)) will improve performance more than multithreading